# Как в XSLT посчитать общее количество элементов в разных файлах?

Tags: xslt

Привет! У меня есть несколько html-файлов с таблицами с разным количеством строк. Я поочерёдно открываю эти таблицы и построчно добавляю в общую таблицу. В моих вычислениях нужно знать сколько строк на данном этапе уже обработано из предыдущих файлов. Вот только переприсвоить переменную нельзя, а взять все строки из предыдущих файлов уже поздно.
Мой кодец:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="html/body/table/tr">
        <xsl:variable name="base" select="td[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="nameF" select="concat('table_',position(),'.html')" />
        <xsl:for-each select="document($nameF)//table/tr">
          <xsl:variable name="Nk" select="$Nk+count('document($nameF)//table/tr')" />
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='position()=1'>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$base" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="number(td[1])+$Nk" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </td>
            <xsl:copy-of select="subsequence(td,2)" />
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Входные файлы имеют вид (различаются количеством строк):

```html
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0, 0.060, 0</td>
    <td>1, 0, 0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  .........
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-0.075, -0.030, 0</td>
    <td>0, 0, 1</td>
    <td>-130</td>
    <td>130</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Где нужно знать? Вам нужно в выходной документ писать `Обработано Х строк`?

Comment: Вам на en.so в комментариях подсказывали вариант с xslt 2.0. Получилось сделать? Если да, напишите ответ.